# Is there a template haskell function for quoting?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am playing with Template Haskell. I want to create a quasi quoter which allows me to create default initializers for records, i.e. something like

```
[record| data Config = { shouldDoX = True; featureY :: Integer, optionZ = Nothing } |]
```

should create a function

```
defaultConfig = Config { shouldDoX = True, optionZ = Nothing }
```

Basically it's the same syntax as data declarations, extended by default values. Now `record` is a custom QuasiQuoter, however there are expressions and types inside which I do not want to parse myself. Ideally I would only have to divide the block inside the curly braces into statements and look for `=` and `::`.

So I'm looking for a function which effectively does the same as quoting with `[e| ...|]` or `[t| ...|]`. I've searched Hoogle for a function `String -> ExpQ` or `String -> Q Exp` but didn't find anything.

**In case I was not clear about what I'm looking for:** I know about QuasiQuoters. As I mentioned: `record` *is* a QuasiQuoter. Now the string that is passed to my quasi quoter contains Expressions (like `Node 7 (Node 8 Nil Nil) Nil`) and Types (like `True` or `Maybe (Either A B)`). I could parse these myself, but I hope that there is a function which will do it for me, just as if I passed the string into a quotation like `[e|...|]`.

So: I'm looking for a function which I can feed an expression as a String, or a Type as a String, and which returns the adequate `Exp` or `Type` object. I believe it must live in the Q monad, since it should evaluate the expression or type based on the context (just like quotations do).

```
functionOfMyDreams "Node 7 (Node 8 Nil Nil) Nil" :: Q Exp
```

Comment: I think [haskell-src-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta) might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think the functions

```
parseExp :: String -> Either String Exp
parseType :: String -> Either String Type
```

from `haskell-src-meta` package are what you want.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta-0.6.0.4/docs/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse-Careful.html

Here is [a self-contained example](https://github.com/nushio3/practice/tree/a38a566c54b41ab9d12480f28027ee5551fb7822/template-haskell/embed-expr) of an quasiquoter that can antiquote and embed Haskell expressions using `haskell-src-meta`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but it would be a function like `String -> Q [Dec]`

To make a quasiquoter you have to create a value of type [QuasiQuoter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.8.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html) which has a four functions of type `String -> Q Blah` where Blah is the Template Haskell type you are splicing in.

In your case you only need to define the declaration quoter.

```
quoteRecord :: String -> Q [Dec]
quoteRecord = ...

record :: QuasiQuoter
record = QuasiQuoter (error "record is not a expression quoter")
                     (error "record is not a pattern quoter")
                     (error "record is not a type quoter")
                     quoteRecord
```

You can then use your record quasiquoter in another file

```
[record| ... |]
```

There is a good walk through on the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation)

You also might want to check out [BNFC-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BNFC-meta) which will generate a quasiquoter from a grammar.

Comment: I think you might have misread my question. I know about QuasiQuoters. However, the link to bnfc-meta is interesting. Edited further explanation into the question.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is antiquoting. If so the wiki explains that process. Also BNFC-meta produces quasiquoters that provide antiquoting.